# SQL Server : get real min between date values of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I have the following table that stores gps mobile point for each minute.

```
CREATE TABLE [POINTS]
(
    [ID_POINTS] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Latitude] [float] NULL,
    [Longitude] [float] NULL,
    [PointDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Activity] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ID_WORKER] [int] NULL,
    [ID_DEVICE] [int] NULL, 
    [Control] [nvarchar](10) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_POINTS] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID_POINTS] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,  
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

See sample data showing the following columns: `id_worker`, `activity` and `pointdate`:

```
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 11:59:38.7510000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:29:01.5680000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:30:06.1930000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:31:07.1960000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:32:13.1960000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:33:19.1930000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:34:21.1800000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:35:23.1720000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:36:24.1730000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:37:24.2190000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:38:29.1790000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:39:31.1720000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:40:34.1620000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:53:11.1670000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:54:12.2140000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:55:12.2140000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:56:14.1710000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:57:18.2150000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:58:24.1740000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 14:59:29.1970000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:00:31.1780000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:01:36.2190000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:02:36.2240000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:03:42.2000000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:04:46.1840000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:05:50.1640000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:06:54.2090000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:07:54.2380000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:08:54.2380000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:10:00.1910000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:11:02.1810000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:12:06.2220000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:13:12.2100000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:14:12.2180000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:15:18.2160000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:16:18.2180000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:17:18.2180000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:18:18.2220000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:19:18.2220000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:20:24.2120000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:21:30.2240000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:22:36.2140000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:23:42.2180000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:24:48.2150000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:25:54.1810000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:26:54.2140000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:27:54.2360000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:29:00.2350000
1   DRAWING 2021-07-31 15:30:06.2200000
```

I need to get total minutes excluding lunch time that it comes from 10:00 to 10:30 and from 14:00 to 15:00

The desired result must be 2 hour 30 min

Comment: These records are points in time - they have no duration - so what you are asking doesn't make a lot of sense, to me. Please explain the logic you want to implement that gives "total minutes". Are you trying to round (up or down) these timestamps to the nearest minute and are then saying that each record covers that minute e.g. 15:17:18.2180000 = 15:17:00 to 15:17:59? Are you also saying that "lunch time" lasts from 10:30 to 14:00?

Comment: Some combination of `WHERE` (to filter out times you're not interested in), `MIN` and `MAX` (to get the range endpoints) and `DATEDIFF` (to calculate the difference) should get you what you want, though from the question it's not precisely clear what that is. (`CASE` may also be needed to subtract ranges you don't want if `MIN` though `MAX` straddle them.)

Comment: Do you mean you want to check that there are no missing entries? If it logs every minute then surely there will be 90 entries in those ranges, not 150.

Comment: from `11:59` to `15:30` is 3 hours and 31 minutes. If you substract 90 minutes of break you will end up with 2 hours and 1 minute, not with your expected 2 hours and 30 min.

Comment: From 11:59 to 14:00 would be a valid range = 121 minutes approx.
From 14:00 to 15:00 would be a Not valid range.
From 15:00 to 15:30 would be a valid range = 30 minutes.
Total time in minutes = 151 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Using LEAD function of SQL Server I can access to next row for calculate duration based on PointDate field for all rows